# When exactly a site uses it's database for retrieval

Tags: database, web, uml, data-retrieval

my knowledge on how a database exactly works is close to zero and I'm trying to understand when exactly a site uses it's database to retrieve information. So for example the site retrieves all the information the moment i load the site(so when i choose for example "funny pictures" it doesn't have to retrieve anything from the database) or it retrieves information only when i make a specific choice? I hope you kind of understand my question, I'm sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how it has been implemented and with whihc technology.
Most of time, It load a specific set of information only relevant of the current context.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on SW technology used, settings and site code. Normally it is set to show something only when needed, but it is possible to change this behaviour.

There is one more possibility you haven't noticed, but often used - for example, you have a set of pictures. You see all their small icons on the page, but the whole picture - only if you click on an icon. Then while you are looking on the icons, or on one of the pictures, others pictures are downloaded at the background, to be quickly shown when needed. Sometimes even some primitive prediction system works, to guess what you'll look at the next time.

And all these behaviours work not only for data from databases, but for all data on the pages.

Again, the main thought - ***it is for you to choose***.